# jQuery focus() not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

When the user clicks the search (magnifying glass) icon on the website, the search bar slides down into view. After the search bar slides down, I want the cursor to start blinking inside the search bar, so the user can start typing right away. But I can't get that cursor to move into the search bar. I've tried everything I can think of to get it to work!

[The website (search icon is in the header)](http://daricecairns.com)

The jQuery code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    //show/hide search bar on icon click
    jQuery('#search-icon').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        jQuery('#mobile-nav').css('display','none');
        jQuery('#search-box').slideToggle('fast',function() {
            if (jQuery('#search-box').css('display') == 'block') {
                window.setTimeout(function() {
                    jQuery('#search-box').focus().val(jQuery('#search-box').val());
                }, 0);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Firstly, the `input` field has an ID of `#search-bar`, not `#search-box`.

Comment: your selector is incorrect, you need to use '#search-box input' as the selector for the focus(); method  and get rid of the window.setTimeout it's meaningless here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed selector id and it worked as you want. Check out the code below.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    //show/hide search bar on icon click
    jQuery('#search-icon').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        jQuery('#mobile-nav').css('display','none');
        jQuery('#search-box').slideToggle('fast',function() {
            if (jQuery('#search-box').css('display') == 'block') {
                window.setTimeout(function() {
                    jQuery('#search-bar').focus().val(jQuery('#search-bar').val());  // changed selector to "search-bar". 
                }, 0);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: WOW, can't believe I missed that. Thanks so much!

Comment: Happy to help @torjinx.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('#search-box').on('focus', function(event){
  var searchQuery = $('#search-box').val();
  console.log(searchQuery);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id='search-box' type='text'/>
```